# Erro de tradução nos botões do template adminLTE

Tags: laravel, template, adminlte

Desenvolvi um projeto que usa o template adminLTE e o Framework Laravel. Mas ao migrar o projeto para o servidor de produção os botões do template ficaram desconfigurado. Estou precisando da ajuda de vocês para solucionar este problema, segue as imagens.

**Projeto no servidor de Produção (Ubutun 16.04 lts)**
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**Projeto no servidor de Teste (Apache 2.4.29)**
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Como resolveu isso? estou com o mesmo problema.

Comment: @gessermigueldapaixao, no item 'Resposta' contém a solução desse problema.

Answer (score 0):

Normalmente acontece porque no arquivo de configuração **config/app.php** a linguagem (idioma) está com caracteres diferentes do nome da pasta de tradução.

Se tiver **pt-br** alterne para **pt-BR** e vice e versa.